# Error when using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm doing a simple MySQL query to count the number of rows a query is returning without the effect of the `LIMIT` clause. I'm using Active Records with Codeigniter PHP framework.

**Problem:** I'm getting an error when `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is used. Why is this so?

**Query**

```
SELECT `listing_id`, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS listing_id FROM (`listings`) LIMIT 100
```

**Error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS listing_id FROM (`listings`) LIMIT 100' at
>   line 1

**Codeigniter Active Records**

```
$this->db->select('listing_id')
            ->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS listing_id', FALSE)
            ->from('listings')
            ->where('price < 1000')
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by('listing_id', 'desc');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use MySql's `count()` function to achieve what you are looking for ie.

```
SELECT `listing_id`, count(*) FROM (`listings`) LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Doesn't this need a GROUP BY statement as well?

Comment: This will give a different result sometimes because SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS disregards LIMIT.

Answer (score 2):

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` doesn't return a value, it's simply a modifier to indicate that the number of rows —where the `LIMIT` clause is not taken into account— should be saved so it can be retrieved later on, by using a second query (without generating the complete result set twice). Think of it the same as the `DISTINCT` keyword.

For more information, please read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) on this topic.